# AudioKit - Midi - How do I determine the state of a know without events?

Tags: ios, midi, audiokit

Sorry, this may be a dumb question, but I am new to MIDI and no musician - I am trying to figure out if I can use a MIDI Controller for some other control application.

I know how to set up the MIDI system and receive MIDI events using AudioKit.midi in iOS.

I am trying to find out if I can determine the state of let's say a Midi Knob, without it sending events? As soon as I start turning a knob I get events - so at the moment in order initialize the system I have to turn every button so it sends an event and the controller setting is being reflected in my software. The controller I have has 16 knobs and I seem to believe that I am missing something? This must be easier, somehow...

I could use relative knobs and keep the state in my code, but my controller wakes up with all dials in absolute mode - so I am thinking there has to be a way?

Any hint would be appreciated :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MIDI specification does not define any such mechanism.

Some devices allow to read the current state of most controls, but only with vendor-specific SysEx messages.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is wondering how to get these vendor-specific SysEx messages: Use a MIDI monitor in a working setup to sniff the communication. I used a virtual dj mixing software and a midi monitoring software called MidiView for mac. Also Serato compatible devices will respond to the Serato system exclusive message:

https://github.com/mixxxdj/mixxx/wiki/serato_sysex